# How to echo the Host's IP address

Tags: html, web, ip-address

I'm deploying the same HTML page across multiple hosts and I need to show the IP address of the host.

I know how to echo the IP address of the visitor, just not how to echo your own IP address!

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Which one? The machine I'm working on right now has 4.

Comment: I need to do it without using PHP ideally as the process is an automated Nginx deployment. I need to do it with as minimal Nginx config as possible.

Answer (score -2):

to show the IP of the host/server you use the following code in PHP:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

Comment: and why exactly was this downvoted :/? the user only stated later that PHP was not possible for the solution?